# i want to create a text file

Tags: android, file-io

When the user clicks the save button a text file should be created and the contents should be stored in the file, but my application just crashes when I do so.

```
public class newfile extends Activity {
    public EditText textBox,textbox2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newfile);
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) { 
                textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText1);
                textbox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);

                String FILENAME = textbox2.getText().toString();
                String value = textBox.getText().toString();
                File("R.raw",value); 

                FileOutputStream fos=null ;
                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                try {
                    fos.write(((String) value).getBytes());
                    fos.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }

            private void File(String string, String value) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }

            private FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String fILENAME,
                    int modePrivate) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

openFileOutput returns null? Mayby thats why your app chrashes?

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line...

```
File("R.raw",value);
```

Delete these methods...

```
private void File(String string, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String fILENAME,
        int modePrivate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Surround this line...

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

...with a `try/catch` block like so...

```
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thank you ihave done the above changes but i still get a dialog in eclipse "this kind of launch is configured to open the debug perspective when it suspends",i wnt to create a file on the go when the user types the name of the file @ filedata he clicks the save button which should create the file by taking the file name from the    xtboxt. i want to store the file in res/raw folder that i have created .please help me out.

Comment: You can't modify the `/res` folder, any of its sub-folders (or any of the files they contain) at runtime. The `/res` folder is for holding stuff packaged at build-time and is basically 'read-only'.

Answer (score 0):

Use getFilesDir() to get the absolute path of your application and use it to create a file in your application folder.
Otherwise, you don't have the right to create files everywhere.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()